# ggplot2 : Bind 2 heatmaps and add a dataframe box in the corner

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, tree, heatmap

I made two heatmaps with the code:

I create the first heatmap

```
heatmap1<-ggplot(mod_mat_constraint, aes(x=Categorie, y=label)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=Value)) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("#86d65e","#404040","#86d65e","#40c5e8","#e84a4a","#86d65e","#404040","#e2e2e2"), breaks=label_text)
```

I create the second heatmap

```
heatmap2<-ggplot(mod_mat_gen_env, aes(x=Categorie, y=label)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=Value)) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("#86d65e","#404040","#86d65e","#40c5e8","#e84a4a","#86d65e","#404040","#e2e2e2"), breaks=label_text)
```

and I add them with a tree with:

```
heatmap2 %>% insert_left(tree) %>% insert_right(heatmap1, width=.5)
```

which gives me:

[image]

and I wondered if there were a way with ggplot2 to add an additional df box at the right corner such as:

[image]

from a dataframe called DF1

```
COL1 COL2  COL3
0.1  Peter USA
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help precisely without a dataset, but to get a table overlaid on your plot, probably the best way would be to use `annotation_custom()` with a `tableGrob()` from the `gridExtra` package.

Here's an example heatmap [pulled right from the R Graph Gallery](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/79-levelplot-with-ggplot2.html) which I used to add in your table as a grob.

```
# Library
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

# Dummy data
x <- LETTERS[1:20]
y <- paste0("var", seq(1,20))
data <- expand.grid(X=x, Y=y)
data$Z <- runif(400, 0, 5)

# Heatmap 
p <- ggplot(data, aes(X, Y, fill= Z)) + 
  geom_tile()

df <- data.frame(COL1=0.1,COL2='Peter',COL3='USA')

# adding the table
p + coord_cartesian(clip='off') +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(r=140)) +
  annotation_custom(
    grob=tableGrob(df, theme=ttheme_default(base_size = 7)),
    xmin=20, xmax=27, ymin=1, ymax=5
  )
```

[image]

You can probably use a similar approach in your case.  Note the few things that I had to do here to get this to work:

- add the grob as `annotation_custom()`.  You will need to play around with the positioning... really just play with those numbers.  Also note you may want to play with the base size to ensure the table is the right aspect ratio compared to your plot.
- Extend the plot margin so that you have the real estate on that side to include the table.
- Turn clipping off so that you can see things outside the plot area properly.

Comment: Ok I see thank you, it works as a charm ! :) I also wondered if you knew another way to bind 2 heatmap next to a tree, I actually use  the package `aplot`  (`heatmap2 %>% insert_left(tree) %>% insert_right(heatmap1, width=.5)` ) but I cannot deal with the width of the first heatmap with this option ..

Comment: haven't had too much experience using that package.  Are you able to use facets?  Like, still you'll need to use `insert_left(tree)`, but what if you made your two heatmaps via facets in `ggplot`, then added the tree to the left of that?  Additionally, if you setup your plots as grobs, with the `grid` or `gridExtra` package, that would allow for a bit more control - just not sure if it will work well with `aplot`.